# iOS Custom UItableviewcell sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Just trying to understand how and if its possible to make custom UItableview with 3 sections of custom cells, similar to below.

```
           Sensor Info
====================== 
Sensor 1: $Value_1   
Sensor 2: $Value_2
Sensor 3: $Value_3
Sensor 4: $Value_4   
Sensor 5: $Value_5
Sensor 6: $Value_6

             Errors
===================
Error 1  :  $error1
Error 2..:  $error2..

       Another Section
========================
Error 1  :  $error1
Error 2..:  $error2..
```

One suggestion might be to add all the content into one array and then populate the table but i need each segment to load after another. Each segments content are generated from methods within the view controller class after a button is pressed. So Sensor Info, Errors, another section and more if i do plan to add later on.

Im having a hard time trying to grasp how to build a table with different row syles for each section. I would like to make all sensor data custom cell and the  subtitle cells or right detail.

Comment: If you are fine with library than please try STCollapseTableView...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many sources and sections you want your table.

You can even have a prototyped cell for each section.

Just verify where you are and handle it like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 44
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if (section == 0) {
        return "Title 1"
    }
    if (section == 1) {
        return "Title 2"
    }          
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return contactPhones.count
    } else if section == 1 {
        return contactEmails.count
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier: String = "Cell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = contactPhones[indexPath.row]["phoneNumber"].stringValue
        cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(flagImageWithCountryCode: contactPhones[indexPath.row]["phoneCountryCode"].stringValue)
    } else if indexPath.section == 1 { 
        cell?.textLabel?.text = contactEmails[indexPath.row]["emailAddress"].stringValue
    }

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Do you have the objective-c version of this code. I have yet to learn swift.

Comment: No but delegates methods from table view are the same, you have to handle just the `if` inside it to reach your goal

Comment: Judging from the code, you are adding three three different Table Views to the viewcontroller in storyboard?

Comment: No. In the example there are 2 tableViews being handled. I'm sorry... will update my answer to fit your needs

Comment: Just didn't realize you wanted sections instead tables... now is ok. You have to check in which section you are and return the correct value for it

Comment: Would it be better to use two table views rather than sections with custom cells?

Comment: It depends on your expected result. Two tables in one view is not recommended, but also not forbidden. Think about the amount of data you have to display. Two tables will have each one its own scroll, which can be a bad user experience.

Comment: Yea I was going to ask that, if they would have individual scrolls or can it be locked to the view. I see in your example you used 1 cell identifier for all the sections, what if i wanted all two sections to look different. Would i create custom classes for the cells and populated based on the section?

Comment: Exactly. There is no restriction, you can have as many sections you want and for each you can have a cell class